# How to close the radwindow on serverside and refresh the parent page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I want to close the [RadWindow](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/contenttemplatevsnavigateurl/defaultcs.aspx) and refresh the parent : how to do this server side :

I have the following case:

Two pages say :

## parent.aspx :

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableViewState ="false">
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

---

and parent.cs

```
  protected void OpenNewWindow(string url, int width, int height,int mode)
        {
            RadWindow newWindow = new RadWindow();
            newWindow.NavigateUrl = url;
            newWindow.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
            newWindow.KeepInScreenBounds = true;
            if (width > 0)
            {
                newWindow.Width = width;


            }
            if (height > 0)
            {
                newWindow.Height = height;
            }
            newWindow.VisibleStatusbar = false;
            if (mode == 0)
            {
                newWindow.DestroyOnClose = true;
                newWindow.InitialBehaviors = WindowBehaviors.Maximize;
            }
            RadWindowManager1.Windows.Add(newWindow);
        }
```

i call this method in the rowcommand of some gridview on my parentpage :

like this :

```
OpenNewWindow("child.aspx", 0, 0,0);
```

---

Now i want on the server side click event of some button on the `child` page to close the rad window and refresh the parent one how to do this ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said, you want to close from code behind. So you can render `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "CloseScript", "refreshParentPage()", true);` from code behind to refresh the parent.

Just add the following code and script in Child Page. No code is needed in parent page.

```
<script>         
    function getRadWindow() {
        var oWindow = null;
        if (window.radWindow)
            oWindow = window.radWindow;
        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow)
            oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
        return oWindow;
    }

    // Reload parent page
    function refreshParentPage() {
        getRadWindow().BrowserWindow.location.reload();
    }
</script>

<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Close" ID="CloseButton" 
    OnClick="CloseButton_Click"/>

protected void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), 
        "CloseScript", "refreshParentPage()", true);
}
```

**Update**:

```
// Redirect page page to url
function redirectParentPage(url) {
    getRadWindow().BrowserWindow.document.location.href = url;
}

// Code behind
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), 
"CloseScript", "redirectParentPage('Parent.aspx')", true);
```

Comment: I get the following message from firefox : `To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.`

Comment: Your parent page was posted back to server previously. If so, you need to make sure parent page is not posted back, before user opens child RadWindow. OR use the **updated code** which redirects parent page to itself instead of reload.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `getRadWindow().close()` method and the `OnClientClose` event.

On Child.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getRadWindow() {
        var oWindow = null;

        if (window.radWindow) 
            oWindow = window.radWindow;
        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) 
            oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;

        return oWindow;
    }

    function clientClose(arg) {   
        getRadWindow().close(arg);
    }

</script>
```

In Child.cs:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "closeScript", "clientClose('');", true);
}
```

When creating your RadWindow in Parent.cs, add the `OnClientClose` event: `newWindow.OnClientClose = "OnChildWindowClosed";`.

And on Parent.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnChildWindowClosed(sender, eventArgs) {
        document.location.reload(); // there may be a cleaner way to do the refresh
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I get the following message from firefox :
`To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.`

Comment: window.location.reload() attempts to perform the last postback again, and you can't prevent that. Try window.location.href = window.location.href instead. It would usually work, unless you have a hash in the URL.

Comment: I believe this is the better approach, because it fires and uses the `OnClientClose` event of RadWindow control. To solve the reload issue, use the function `redirectParentPage` from the update of @Win 's answer above. Use `getRadWindow().close(arg);` to pass the argument through to the function `OnChildWindowClosed` and use it there with `window.location.href = eventArgs.get_argument();`

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to force closing rad window, just put it inside update panel like that :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Block">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>

       </ContentTemplate>
    </telerik:RadWindow>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Important: you have to apply this properties to the update panel :

UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Block"

​

then inside the button you want to execute the close command perform :

```
UpdatePanel1.update()
```

this command will close radwindow and no refresh to your Webpage and no need to javascript, I tried it.

Comment: Don't do that unless you understand why it works and why it is a bad idea and what issue it can cause. Review this article first: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/how-to/how-to-use-radwindow-with-ajax