# How to close a RadWindow not usting the default "X"?

Tags: javascript, telerik, radwindow

I have a RadWindow as following:

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="PIQRadWindow" Modal="true" runat="server" Skin="Default" Behaviors="Close,Move" CssClass="RadWindowCustomClass" VisibleStatusbar="false" width="400px" OnClientClose="RadWindowClose">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <pd:uc_PopupDropdown ID="pdPIQScore" enableviewstate="False" Draggable="true" isInternal="true" ISOC="ProjectInstructionQuality" DivContent = "pdPIQScore" ScriptPrefix = "OFS_" runat="server" />  
    </ContentTemplate>     
    </telerik:RadWindow>
```

I want it to be closed within a onclick event I defined. I tried to use

```
   function getRadWindow() {
      var oWindow = null;
      if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
      else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
      return oWindow;
   }

   function clientClose() {   
      getRadWindow().close();
   }
```

But it's not working for me. Error message: "window.frameElement is null".

Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Finally I find I can still use $find("<%=PIQRadWindow.ClientID%>").close() to close it. Not necessarily make it so complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use $find() when using the ContentTemplate. You can either keep a reference in a global JS variable (you can populate the variable in Sys.Application.Load), or create functions that will open and close the dialog and call them whenever needed. Check this demo's code: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/contenttemplatevsnavigateurl/defaultcs.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this post? If so, please share some more of your code so we can see exactly whats going on.
[How to close the radwindow on serverside and refresh the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640301/how-to-close-the-radwindow-on-serverside-and-refresh-the-parent-page)

Comment: Yeah, they all use similar getRadWindow() function. But I got error from this function: window.frameElement is null.

Comment: Are you able to access the window from the code behind by name?

Comment: Your control lists "RadWindowClose" yet your function says clientClose()

Comment: @Rickjames No, I can't access the window in "uc_PopupDropdown". Oh maybe that's why. So do you know how can I make it work in this way? I mean, keep using uc_PopupDropdown in contenttemplate. THANKS!